# Are there sequences in Dense subset of Normed space that converging to an arbitrary point in Normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am studying banach spaces. I encountered with following theorem and stuck with it for a while, a little help might be nice.

Let $V$ be a Normed Space,
if $D_\alpha \subseteq V$ is densely defined in $V$,i.e $\overline{D_\alpha} = V$ ,where $\overline{D_\alpha}$ denotes closure of $D_\alpha$, Then for all points $p\in V$ there exist a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $D_\alpha$, such that $lim_{n\to\infty}\{x_n\} = p$.

Comment: I am confused. That is literally the definition of a set being dense. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Since $p\in V=\overline{D_\alpha}$, for each $n$ there exists $x_n\in D_\alpha$ such that $\|x_n-p\|<1/n$.